# Azure cloud app subdomain pointing to actual domain

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, cloud, azure, application

Say we have a domain xyz.com registered with some registrar ... we pointed that domain to the name server of our dedicated server where the DNS will be hosted for that domain.

Now, we just want that dedicated server to host the emails coming and the domain will point to abc.cloudapp.net (azure cloud app, they don't provide any static IP ... and only public url is given)

Now, someone please helping me in editing/creating the DNS file on our dedicated server to make sure things work properly... if possible past here minimum settings we need in DNS file to make sure mails are on dedicated server and app is on cloud...

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

The configuration details are going to vary hugely depending on what DNS server you're using, but what you want is:

1. an MX record that points at your dedicated server
2. a CNAME record for abc that points at the cloud app name.